# How do I remove a locked Logical Volume ([pvmove0]) left over after a disk error?

Tags: linux, lvm

Following some disk errors while I was moving some extents, I now have a hidden locked [pvmove0] which doesn't seem to have any physical extents assigned, although it is 4Mb long!

```
# lvs -a -o+seg_pe_ranges a/pvmove0
  LV        VG   Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert PE Ranges
  [pvmove0] a    vwC---v--- 4.00m
```

I've had this happen a couple of years ago on a different system (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/linux.debian.user/fPXQ_y7sgoI/XUjcQmorWXIJ)) but didn't get many replies (only 1) and can't remember how/if I fixed it.

The simple `lvremove a/pvmove0`' (optionally with `--force`) results in the message `Can't remove locked LV pvmove0`.

`pvmove --abort` does nothing. The presence of this volume doesn't seem to affect other moves (which simply use [pvmove1]).

In the config, the LV shows:

```
            pvmove0 {
                    id = "54veYD-hM8r-j214-MOD1-FGnV-3g7t-jRlZ7W"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "LOCKED"]
                    flags = []
                    creation_host = "zotac"
                    creation_time = 1394764593      # 2014-03-14 02:36:33 +0000
                    allocation_policy = "contiguous"
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 1        # 4 Megabytes

                            type = "error"
                    }
            }
```

I noticed there's no physical volume associate with the LV.

My enquiry a few years ago got the suggestion to try `dmsetup remove`. Unfortunately, this requires a device name and `dmsetup info a-pvmove0` reports that the `Device does not exist`.

I suspect that the only fix is to manually edit the config file to remove the offending LV and then use `vgcfgrestore` but would assume that I'm not the only person to have this problem and would think there's a series of commands to fix it!

[FYI: the `disk errors` were the almost simultaneous failure of 2 out of 3 disks in a RAID array; fortunately one the drives only had a few bad blocks so I was able to recover all but a few megabytes of a 500Gb volume using `ddrescue`]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I gave up waiting for answers and tried the simple solution of editing the config file. that is:

1. `vgcfgbackup a`
2. Edit `/etc/lvm/backup/a` and remove the definition of Logical Volume `pvmove0`
3. `vgcfgrestore a`

The volume disappeared and there don't seem to be any side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with power going out during a `pvmove`. Reissuing the command made the process resume without issues.